# Access table into CSV with columns

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to convert MS Access table into CSV.

MS Access table:

[image]

Python 2.7:

```
conn_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' + file1 + ';'
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM EMP')

with open(csvfile, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([i[0] for i in cursor.description])
    writer.writerows(cursor)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

But getting unexpected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write column values as rows, that's what expands their characters into individual cells. To write the header use:

```
writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description])
```

Then use `writer.writerows()` to write the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Use Pandas to Read SQL and Write to CSV

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
```

open connection

```
conn_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' + file1 + ';'
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
```

Read SQl Query Result into Pandas Dataframe

```
query = "SELECT * FROM EMP"
dataf = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
conn .close()
```

Save to CSV

```
dataf.to_csv('./file_path')
```